# is signup and signin same for facebook and google android

Tags: android, facebook-login

I am creating a signup sign-in system for android. I want to know that is signup and signing process same for Facebook? when I first press the signup button from my activity I get signup successfully. I created a Facebook signup system successfully. but I want to know that how to log in a registered user from fb. is the `Signin` and `Signup` process same for Facebook? when I do this I get a message `you previously signed in "app Name"`.

same for google also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I found that Sign n and sign up for Facebook is the same for facebook.